# After deleting an item , data shows null

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

in my actions, I am deleting data as follows

```
    const deleteEmailFooter = (emailID) => async (dispatch) => {
      try {
        console.log('email id', emailID);
        const response = await api.delete(`/signatures/${emailID}`);
        return dispatch({
          type: "DELETE_EMAIL_FOOTER",
          payload: emailID,
        });
      } catch (error) {
        throw dispatch({
          type: "DELETE_EMAIL_FAILED",
          payload: error.data,
        });
      }
    };
```

here is my reducer

```
const initialState = {
  emailFooters: [],
};
const videoFooterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case "GET_EMAIL_FOOTER":
      return action.payload ;
      case "DELETE_EMAIL_FOOTER":
      return state.emailFooters.filter((x) => x.id !== action.payload);

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

and I am displaying this data in one of my components like this

```
......
       const signatures = useSelector((state) => state.videoFooterReducer.emailFooters);
       .......
       console.log("signatures...", signatures); // before deleting there is data , but after 
   deleting its shows in a console undefined 

      useEffect(() => {
        getEmailSignatures();
      }, []);
    
      const getEmailSignatures = async (signatures) => {
        try {
          dispatch(actions.videoFooterActions.getEmailFooter());
        } catch (error) {}
      };
      
      
     return(
        <div>
             {signatures.map((signature) => (
                <SignatureListTemplate signature={signature} key={signature.id} />
              ))}
        </div>
     );
```

Why its null while there is data still there which are not deleted ? error:  `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your reducer code like this see if it fixes the issue

```
const initialState = {
  emailFooters: [],
};
const videoFooterReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
      case "GET_EMAIL_FOOTER":
      return action.payload ;
      case "DELETE_EMAIL_FOOTER":
      const newEmails = [...state.emailFooters.filter((x) => x.id !== 
      action.payload]);
      return {
         ...state,
         emailFooters:newEmails
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

the issue is because in your code you return the email footers and it changes your state in reducer into an array instead of object `const inisialState = [your data]`  and i think it isn't acceptable and even if it is this way is better because you might have more state